# how to display multiple forms on a page using formset

Tags: django, django-forms, django-views

I'm making a form to add an organization record

```
models.py:
class Entity(BaseModel):
    title = models.CharField(_('Заголовок'), max_length=255, db_index=True)
    short_description = models.CharField(_('Короткое описание'), max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
    body = models.TextField(verbose_name=_('Описание'), max_length=4096)
    ordering = models.IntegerField(_('Порядок'), default=0, db_index=True)
    test_field = models.TextField(verbose_name=_('Тестовое поле'), max_length=4096)
    test_field2 = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True,null=True, verbose_name=_('Тестовое поле 2'))

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('ordering',)
        verbose_name = _('Форма')
        verbose_name_plural = _('Формы')


class Industry(BaseModel):
    name = models.CharField(_('Название'),max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
    entity = models.ForeignKey(
        Entity, verbose_name=_('Организация'), related_name='industries', on_delete=models.CASCADE
    )

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('ordering',)
        verbose_name = _('Отрасль')
        verbose_name_plural = _('Отрасли')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class BaseAddressClass(BaseModel):
    address = models.TextField(verbose_name=_('Адрес'), blank=True, null=True)
    oktmo = models.CharField(verbose_name=_('ОКТМО'),max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
    postal_code = models.CharField(verbose_name=_('Почтовый индекс'), max_length=20, blank=True, null=True)
    entity = models.ForeignKey(
        Entity, verbose_name=_('Организация'), related_name='addresses', on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True
    )

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('ordering',)


class PhysicalAddress(BaseAddressClass):
    class Meta:
        verbose_name = _('Физический адрес')
        verbose_name_plural = _('Физические адреса')


class LegalAddress(BaseAddressClass):
    class Meta:
        verbose_name = _('Юридический адрес')
        verbose_name_plural = _('Юридические адреса')
```

i want the page to show the branches in a list and also have the ability to add addresses. for this in the EntityForm, i added the industry. The form with the address added inlineformset_factory.for rendering the formset i am using django-formset.js.

```
forms.py:
class EntityForm(forms.ModelForm):
    industry = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=models.Industry.objects.all())

    class Meta:
        fields = '__all__'
        exclude = ('ordering', 'status')
        model = models.Entity


PhysicalAddressFormSet = inlineformset_factory(
    models.Entity, models.PhysicalAddress, form=EntityForm,
    fields=('address', 'oktmo', 'postal_code'), extra=1, max_num=1, validate_max=1, can_delete=False
)


views.py:
class EntityView(BaseTemplateView, CreateView):
    template_name = 'accounts/articles_list.html'
    model = accounts_models.Entity
    form_class = forms.EntityForm
    success_url = 'success/'

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        self.object = None
        form_class = self.get_form_class()
        form = self.get_form(form_class)
        phys_form = forms.PhysicalAddressFormSet()
        return self.render_to_response(
            self.get_context_data(form=form, phys_form=phys_form))
```

```
template:
 <div class="container py-5">
        <form action="." method="post">
            {{- csrf_input -}}
            <div>
                {{ form.title.errors }}
                {{ form.title }}
                {{ form.body.errors }}
                {{ form.slug }}
                {{ form.slug.errors }}
                {{ form.body }}
                {{ form.test_field.errors }}
                {{ form.test_field }}
                {{ form.test_field2.errors }}
                {{ form.test_field2 }}
                {{ form.industry }}
            </div>
            <fieldset>
                <legend>Волженная форма</legend>

                {{ phys_form.management_form }}
                {{ phys_form.non_form_errors }}


                <table class="table table-hover">
                    {% for form in phys_form %}
                        <tr class="inline {{ phys_form.prefix }}">
                            {{ form }}
                        </tr>
                    {% endfor %}
                </table>
            </fieldset>

            <input type="submit" value="Save" class="submit"/>
        </form>

 <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $(function () {
                $(".inline.{{ phys_form.prefix }}").formset({
                    prefix: "{{ phys_form.prefix }}",
                })
            })
        })
    </script>
```

In this case, it turns out that the field industry is displayed in the list, but it is also added and displayed in PhysicalAddressFormSet. How can I do the right thing to display it correctly?

Comment: Could you please show your template. Do you know that you can iterate over a formset: `for form in formset`

Comment: @AndreyBorzenko, added. yes, i tried using this but the result is the same   `{% for item in phys_form %}<div class="inline {{ phys_form.prefix }}"><span>{{ item.label }}</span>{{ item }}</div>{% endfor %}`

Comment: i wanted to make this form ![Valid XHTML](https://prnt.sc/uo5zxp).